# Unable to link native library in OpenCV Android sample

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have OpenCV code (c++), which I want to use in Android. To do this I have to use [Android NDK](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html). I downloaded [OpenCV package for Android development](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/) (ver. 2.4.0) and did all steps from that manual. Basic samples (Java API only) run without problems. Sample #3 *(Tutorial 3 (Advanced) - Add Native OpenCV)* builds from ndk-builder correctly. But always got exception when I'm trying to run/debug it on device from eclipse:

```
Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/opencv/samples/tutorial3/Sample3View;
```

In this line:

```
System.loadLibrary("native_sample");
```

Here's full logcat log:

```
05-31 23:41:45.976: W/ActivityThread(9708): Application org.opencv.samples.tutorial3 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
05-31 23:41:45.983: I/System.out(9708): Sending WAIT chunk
05-31 23:41:45.983: I/dalvikvm(9708): Debugger is active
05-31 23:41:46.179: I/System.out(9708): Debugger has connected
05-31 23:41:46.179: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:46.382: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:46.585: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:46.788: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:46.983: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:47.186: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:47.389: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:47.585: I/System.out(9708): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-31 23:41:47.788: I/System.out(9708): debugger has settled (1463)
05-31 23:41:47.819: D/szipinf(9708): Initializing inflate state
05-31 23:41:47.866: I/Sample::Activity(9708): Instantiated new class org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native
05-31 23:41:48.909: D/dalvikvm(9708): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
05-31 23:41:51.770: I/Sample::Activity(9708): onCreate
05-31 23:41:59.283: W/dalvikvm(9708): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/opencv/samples/tutorial3/Sample3View;
05-31 23:42:01.965: D/AndroidRuntime(9708): Shutting down VM
05-31 23:42:01.965: W/dalvikvm(9708): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native.onCreate(Sample3Native.java:21)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native_sample: findLibrary returned null
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     at org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3View.<clinit>(Sample3View.java:48)
05-31 23:42:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9708):     ... 14 more
```

I find solutions for the same problem but none of them didn't help me:

1. [Native OpenCV Samples for Android throws UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645301/native-opencv-samples-for-android-throws-unsatisfiedlinkerror)
2. [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/NpnKPVdwzJ4)
3. [Major OpenCV-Android for Windows Installing and Running Issues](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/OPgSzWRxBXo) (no answer)

Also I have tested it on different devices and Android API versions.

My system configuration:

```
astor@astor-K42Jv:~$ uname -a
Linux astor-K42Jv 3.2.0-24-generic-pae #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 18:54:21 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

---

I've been tried to fix this problem for 4 nights (it's my free time :) ), but with no luck. I really need this for my thesis, so any help will be appreciated.

---

**Update:** I have tested this sample on Windows 7 (64), but result is the same.

It seems that this is OpenCV bug.

---

**Update:** Build log:

```
astor@astor-K42Jv:/opt/eclipse-android/workspace/OpenCV-2.4.0-samples/tutorial-3-native$ ndk-build 
Install        : libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
Install        : libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
Install        : libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
Install        : libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
Install        : libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
Install        : libnative_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_sample.so
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-system libraries in linker flags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669518/non-system-libraries-in-linker-flags)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whoohoo!

Finally I found solution for this problem by myself!

I decided to debug line:

```
System.loadLibrary("native_sample");
```

To do this I downloaded android source code from Android-SDK and then attached source folder *(/opt/android-sdk-linux/sources/android-15)* to my project.
After this I found that error was:

```
Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:    37 could not load needed library 'libopencv_java.so' for 'libhello-jni.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libopencv_java.so' not found)
```

And really this library is not in `lib` directory. I don't know why but `ndk-build` ignored it. So i decided to copy and load it manualy. For this I copied `libopencv_java.so` from `/opt/OpenCV-2.4.0/libs/armeabi-v7a` and also edited java code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); //load opencv_java lib
    System.loadLibrary("native_sample");
}
```

Actually similar problems are:

1. [Can not load Opencv libraries in necessitas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491799/can-not-load-opencv-libraries-in-necessitas)
2. [Android OpenCV: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958549/android-opencv-cannot-dlopen-camera-wrapper-library)

From second solution I found that I can load libraries using [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html), but I haven't tried it yet.

So I will write simple bash-script that will do it (just copy) for myself.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Even with the inclusion of two lines, I'm facing this issue on some devices.

Comment: Could you please tell me where you copy /opt/OpenCV-2.4.0/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so  to? I'm currently facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Instead of loading your native library  as

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("YOUR_LIBRARY");
}
```

load your library after opencv manager is connected in "onManagerConnected" method in you "BaseLoaderCallBack". Following is my code snippet working for me

```
public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch(status){
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "manager connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.loadLibrary("MYNATIVELIB");
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

You're at a higher level than the actual problem. See ["Getting started with the NDK"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), when you run

```
    cd <project>
    <ndk>/ndk-build
```

... what does it say? (Remember to use the cygwin window and not a dos prompt).

Comment: What do you mean "what does it say?" If build log then see **update** of my question (I build from linux).

Comment: Hm.. gonna sound stupid, but did you clean the project after the ndk-build? Also, check the "hook" or whatever it's called, it looks like 
... void Java_com_hw_ndk_HWNDKActivity_helloLog(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring logThis) ... it has to correspond to com.hw.ndk (the package name).  I'm new to this myself.

Comment: Of course I don't clean project after build. Even after run program on device, libraries are still in lib folder. Maybe you mean javah utility? If so, then yes, I checked function name.

Comment: My understanding is that Eclipse isn't really integrated into the building process (of the native code). When you run ndk-build, then it compiles the native library, but Eclipse doesn't really know about it. So you have to Project-->Clean after every NDK build. Then run it in Eclipse.

Comment: My actions: 1. `ndk-build clean` 2. `ndk-build` 3. project->clean (build automaticaly is unset) 4. debug as android application. Result is the same.

Comment: I found a solution - check out my answer. But anyway thanks for help.