# javacv for android

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I'm trying to use OpenCV on android

I created my android project, added `javacv.jar` and `iavacpp.jar` to the build path, created the `lib` folder and copied the `*.so` files from `javacv-arm.jar` to `libs/armeabi`.

All `jar` & `*.so` files are version 2.4.2.

When I run the app, I created a test button. When it is clicked I'm calling this line:

```
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("file:///android_asset//"+"pic1.jpg");
```

and get the following crash

```
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.myapp.MainActivity.runTest(MainActivity.java:260)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.myapp.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:174)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     ... 13 more
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     ... 17 more
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   124 could not load needed library 'libopencv_core.so' for 'libjniopencv_core.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libopencv_core.so' not found)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:444)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:368)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:131)
03-12 19:22:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(4524):     ... 21 more
03-12 19:22:12.243: D/dalvikvm(4524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2368K, 16% free 16864K/20039K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 50ms
```

Am I missing `libopencv_core.so`? If so, where can I find it built for version 2.4.2?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857301/unable-to-link-native-library-in-opencv-android-sample ? the "LoadLibrary" part?

Comment: Nope, i will try that. but.. where can i find libopencv_core.so?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure by now you've figured it out. download javacv-0.5-cppjars.zip, inside it extract the contents of opencv-2.4.5-android-arm.jar. you'll find libopencv_core.so in there and several other .so files