# Android native libs not found

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm testing opencv for android with native support. I have a simple app that change the camera image with its canny representation.

The problem I'm facing is that it works fine in a Moto G 1st gen (Android 5.0) but it doesn't in a Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo (API level 17)

The error I get is:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load
>   library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1636): could not load library
>   "libopencv_java3.so" needed by "libnative-lib.so"; caused by
>   load_library(linker.cpp:746): library "libopencv_java3.so" not found

I double check that that file exists under `jniLibs/<ABI>` and also with What's my ABI app from store check that both are `armeabi-v7a`.

I'm out of ideas. Any clue?

EDiT: Added more information

I forgot to mention that I'm using OpenCV for Android v3.1 and if you need the code you could find it here: https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio

Comment: @ReazMurshed your edit removed critical information from this question triggering a mistaken answer, *never* do that again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857301/unable-to-link-native-library-in-opencv-android-sample/29640808#29640808) stackOverflow answer.

Basically, what it says is to call *System.loadLibrary* **after BaseLoaderCallback returns LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS**.

Also while researching for this I came across with *ReLinker v1.2* that states to be a robust method for loading native libraries. I'm also thinking in giving it a try. [Here](https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker) you can find its GitHub repo

Answer (score -1):

Please add below folder inside **jniLib**

```
armeabi
```

and `x86`

because of both device have diff processor

Comment: You are mistaken.  Neither device is an x86.

Comment: In jniLibs folder I already have those folders and many orders (all the folders inside native libs of opencv for Android)